# Compute $\mathbb{Q}[x] \otimes _{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I have to compute $\mathbb{Q}[x] \otimes _{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}$. I think this is an extension of scalar and that
$$\mathbb{Q}[x] \otimes _{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}[x].$$
For the universal property there is an omomorphism
$$\phi:\mathbb{Q}[x] \otimes _{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}[x]$$ such that
$$\phi(f(x) \otimes \alpha)= \alpha \cdot f(x).$$
This is injective but I have no idea how to prove that this is an isomorphism, in other words: for every $g(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ can i found an element $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $g(x)=\alpha \cdot f(x)$ ?

Comment: note that the $\Bbb C$ is inconsequential. For any $A$-algebra $B$, we have $A[x] \otimes_A B \cong B[x]$

Comment: As a hint: remember that elements of $\mathbb{Q}[x]\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{C}$ are *not* all of the form $f(x)\otimes \alpha$, but rather ,that they are sums of these kinds of elements.

Comment: Thank you @JasonDeVito, I considered only the “pure” elements. It’s very easy to complete the proof whit your hint.

Comment: Thank you @LukasHeger, it’s a result very interesting and awesome.

Comment: @Mario:  Please feel free to write down an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple proof uses the Yoneda Lemma. For any $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $R$, we have

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Hom(\mathbb{Q}[X] \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}, R) &\cong
Hom(\mathbb{Q}[X], R) \times Hom(\mathbb{C}, R) \\
&\cong R \times Hom(\mathbb{C}, R) \\
&\cong Hom(\mathbb{C}[X], R)
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

Here, $Hom$ means $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra homomorphisms, and $\cong$ refers to natural isomorphisms in $R$.

Therefore, we see that, as $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras, we have $\mathbb{Q}[X] \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}[X]$ by the Yoneda Lemma.